Connection Between V'zos Habracha & Bereishes
On Simchas Torah we read the end of V'zos Habracha and the begining of Bereishes - is there any special connection between them? Maybe something similiar about the Pesukim or the story line?

V'zos Habracha talks about the children of Jacob, who are introduced in Sefer Bereshis; V'zos Habracha ends with lamed and Bereshis begins with beis, which spells leiv (heart)

On the first answer - I am talking about the first PARSHA specifically & on the second - what about Leiv?

Rashi on the word בראשית says:

בשביל התורה שנקראת ראשית… ובשביל ישראל שנקראו ראשית.

Simply put, the world was created for the two things called Reishis:
the Torah and Bnei Yisrael.
The blessings of Bnei Yisrael are thus very much intertwined with both the creation of the world and the beginning of the Torah.

A year ago, I wrote this pertinent article, where just past the halfway point is a section beginning with the caption Comparing Bereishis to V'zos - המגיד מראשית אחרית and then has the subsequent section beginning Let's Explore How וזאת הברכה is Very Connected to בראשית!.  There
you will find some interesting connections between the very end of the Torah and the very beginning.
Among those connections is a great one that I can briefly highlight here.  It's based on Rav Chaim Kanievsky's take on the Rokeach's take on the following well known Rashi:

בראשית ברא - אֵין הַמִּקְרָא הַזֶּה אוֹמֵר אֶלָּא דָּרְשֵׁנִי, כְּמוֹ שֶׁדְּרָשׁוּהוּ רַבּוֹתֵינוּ
בִּשְׁבִיל הַתּוֹרָה שֶׁנִקְרֵאת "רֵאשִׁית דַּרְכּוֹ" (משלי ח:כב)
וּבִשְׁבִיל יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁנִקְרְאוּ "רֵאשִׁית תְּבוּאָתֹה" (ירמיה ב:ג)

The peirush of the רוקח on the end of וזאת הברכה appears below:
(יצא לאור ע"י יואל קלוגמאן תשל"ט - תשמ"א, הערות מאת הרה"ג ר' חיים קניבסקי)

While the dashes indicate that parts of the original manuscript of the רוקח were unclear, Rav Chaim Kanievsky's notes indicate the following educated guess to the lines:

החומש מתחיל בראשית ומסיים ישראל ואין ראשית אלא ישראל (ירמיהו ב) "קודש
ישראל ראשית", בראשית בגימטריא ישראל בחר בעמים. לכך סיים התורה ישראל,
התורה כלולה בישראל

that the Chumash begins with the word בראשית and ends with the word ישראל since ישראל itself is considered a type of ראשית and therefore the Torah is filled with ישראל from beginning to end.
